# Create Picker Using Parsed Array

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, swiftui

I am trying to create a picker using an array that is built from an API call (if that's even how to word it). I can create a list just fine with the array but the Picker doesn't show up at all. Not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code. I'm new and experimenting with APIs for the first time so bear with me.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct NHLAPI: View {
    @State private var teams = [Team]()
    @State private var teamsDict = [String: Int]()
    
    @State private var selectedTeam = "Anaheim Ducks"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Teams", selection: $selectedTeam) {
                ForEach(teams, id: \.id) { team in
                    Text(team.name)
                }
            }
            List(teams, id: \.id) { team in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("\(team.name) \(Int(teamsDict[team.name] ?? 1))")
                }
            }
            .task {
                await loadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams") else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data) {
                teams = decodedResponse.teams
                
                for team in teams {
                    teamsDict[team.name] = team.id
                }
            }
        } catch {
            return
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let copyright: String
    let teams: [Team]
}

// MARK: - Team
struct Team: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, link: String
    let venue: Venue
    let abbreviation, teamName, locationName, firstYearOfPlay: String
    let division, conference: Conference
    let franchise: Franchise
    let shortName: String
    let officialSiteURL: String
    let franchiseID: Int
    let active: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, link, venue, abbreviation, teamName, locationName, firstYearOfPlay, division, conference, franchise, shortName
        case officialSiteURL = "officialSiteUrl"
        case franchiseID = "franchiseId"
        case active
    }
}

// MARK: - Conference
struct Conference: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, link: String
}

// MARK: - Franchise
struct Franchise: Codable {
    let franchiseID: Int
    let teamName, link: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case franchiseID = "franchiseId"
        case teamName, link
    }
}

// MARK: - Venue
struct Venue: Codable {
    let name, link, city: String
    let timeZone: TimeZone
}

// MARK: - TimeZone
struct TimeZone: Codable {
    let id: String
    let offset: Int
    let tz: String
}


struct NHLAPI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NHLAPI()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach. I included `Hashable` to most models and
`Identifiable` to `Team`. Used `selectedTeam: Team?` and a matching tag in the `Picker`.

```
struct NHLAPI: View {
    @State private var teams = [Team]()
    @State private var teamsDict = [String: Int]()
    
    @State private var selectedTeam: Team? // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Picker("Teams", selection: $selectedTeam) {
                ForEach(teams) { team in  // <-- here
                    Text(team.name)
                        .tag(team as Team?) // <-- here
                }
            }.padding(20)
            
            List(teams) { team in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("\(team.name) \(Int(teamsDict[team.name] ?? 1))")
                }
            }
            .task {
                await loadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams") else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data) {
                teams = decodedResponse.teams
                for team in teams {
                    teamsDict[team.name] = team.id
                }
                // -- here
                if let teem = teams.first(where: {$0.name == "Anaheim Ducks"}) {
                    selectedTeam = teem
                } else {
                    selectedTeam = teams.first
                }
            }
        } catch {
            return
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let copyright: String
    let teams: [Team]
}

// MARK: - Team
struct Team: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable { // <-- here
    let id: Int
    let name, link: String
    let venue: Venue
    let abbreviation, teamName, locationName, firstYearOfPlay: String
    let division, conference: Conference
    let franchise: Franchise
    let shortName: String
    let officialSiteURL: String
    let franchiseID: Int
    let active: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, link, venue, abbreviation, teamName, locationName, firstYearOfPlay, division, conference, franchise, shortName
        case officialSiteURL = "officialSiteUrl"
        case franchiseID = "franchiseId"
        case active
    }
}

// MARK: - Conference
struct Conference: Hashable, Codable { // <-- here
    let id: Int
    let name, link: String
}

// MARK: - Franchise
struct Franchise: Hashable, Codable { // <-- here
    let franchiseID: Int
    let teamName, link: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case franchiseID = "franchiseId"
        case teamName, link
    }
}

// MARK: - Venue
struct Venue: Hashable, Codable { // <-- here
    let name, link, city: String
    let timeZone: TimeZone
}

// MARK: - TimeZone
struct TimeZone: Hashable, Codable { // <-- here
    let id: String
    let offset: Int
    let tz: String
}
```

You can also select a different `Picker` style, or wrap it in a `Form`, such as

```
 Form {
     Picker(...)
 }.frame(height: 123)
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you?